# Script based reserved key word not accpted but it's accept in tag

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, reserved-words

Here I come up with question about **Reserved words**.  As per my knowledge a keyword can not be a variable.

I've faced a issue about passing reserved word string as a argument in both script based code but not face any error while wrote a same code in tag based. My question here is , I passed argument name as **For**.If it's reserved word mean we could not able to use both tag & script based right. **How the reserved word accept in tag based code ?** Correct me if I'm wrong understood anything.

**FYR :** I've attached my code and successful resule for tag based code and error for script based code.

```
<cfset testCall = callFunc( a=10,For=20)>
Out put :#testCall#

<cfscript>
    testCall = callFunc( a=10,For=20);
    writeDump(testCall);

</cfscript>

<cffunction name="callFunc" access="public" returntype="Any">
    <cfargument name="a" required="true">
    <cfargument name="For" required="true">
    <cfreturn ARGUMENTS.a * ARGUMENTS.For>
</cffunction>
```

Output : 200 ( This is an tag based output )

The below issue is script based code,

[image]

Could any one know why it's was happened ? Or correct me if I'm wrong understood. Thanks in advance !

Comment: 1. What version of ColdFusion? 2. I suspect this is an undocumented anti-feature. For all we know, `callFunc` is how the ColdFusion internals do something 3. Consider putting in a bug report to https://tracker.adobe.com

Comment: I'm using cf 11.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `for` does not mean anything in the tag language. There is not a `for` loop in tags (at least not in that syntax), it is only used in script.

Comment: I wouldn't try using `for` as a variable name in *any* language ;-) It's just too common a reserved words  There may not be a `<cffor`> tag, but it's definitely used in cfscript. My guess is you're running afoul of some internal cfscript parser that sees `for` as a command in that context.

Comment: Yes @Miguel-F & Ageax. That's why I mentioned it as "A key word can not be a variable" This is an basic rule of programming. So that I'm asking about how we can use it in tag itself. 
Currently I switch cf11 to 18 so I changed tag to script for my code. Client used 'For' as a argument ( Like he used Final, etc...). But while converting to script it's not allowed. 

So while work for  improvement we can focus on only reduce code / load time etc.. But we can't focus on arguments name. Right.?

Comment: (cont'd) Notice there's a separate section on [keywords in script syntax](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/elements-of-cfml/reserved-words-in-coldfusion.html)? If you want to convert the CFML code to cfscript, unfortunately you may have to change some variable names.

Comment: (Edit) They used "final" as a variable name? Yipes! CFML and CFScript are kind of two different "languages" (for lack of a better word). While you might hope any CFML code would work the exact same way in cfscript - you can't depend on that. CFScript has syntax elements that CFML doesn't. Therefore some things will work or be reserved words in one, but not in the other.

Comment: I would have to echo Ageax in that it's never a good idea to use common reserved words. And what's worse is when it doesn't throw a hard error like this but has a silent error that can be an extreme pain to troubleshoot, if it's even noticed.

Comment: Yes @Shawn. That is what I felt before find the bug.This kind of bug can be found by very deep eye on that part :) . But interesting to me.

Comment: It's already hard enough to name things, but throw in Reserved Words (or words that are likely to _become_ Reserved Words), and it's enough to make you pull your hair out.  :-)

Comment: It's *not* a bug. The syntax of the two are different, so of course the reserved words are different too - as noted in Adobe's own docs. IMO the only thing that might be considered a bug is the poor error handling ;-)