# How to use reserved keyword as variable in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2018

I have to use the reserved keyword "function" as variable name in ColdFusion.
How can I do the same?
I was trying with @ symbol but that didn't work.
Any snippet will be helpful

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use that as your variable name? That's a ridiculous requirement.

Comment: Something like `variables[ "function" ] = "some value";`?

Comment: You can't use any reserved keywords as variable name. I've already posted some detailed question & answer here. Please check it and confirm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059425/script-based-reserved-key-word-not-accpted-but-its-accept-in-tag

Comment: @Kannan.P, you posted a link to a question for which the only answer was deleted.  The person asking this question might not be able to see it.  Maybe you should answer this question.

Comment: @Miguel-F - This appears to be an extension of [their other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103800/how-to-resolve-coldfusion-analyzer-error-while-upgrading).  Totally agreed on changing the name *everywhere* if at all possible and avoid continued headaches like this in the future.

Comment: That particular thread has `function` as a column name in a database table.  If this is the same problem, renaming the column might not be possible because the db is part of a purchased application.  If this is the case, double quoting the column name in the applicable `cfquery` tags might solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve ColdFusion analyzer error while upgrading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103800/how-to-resolve-coldfusion-analyzer-error-while-upgrading)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the context of the variable, but here are some observations and possible workarounds:

## tag syntax

### variable

```
<!--- works with ACF 10, 11, 2016, 2018 --->
<!--- works with Lucee 4+ --->
<cfset function = "function">
<cfoutput>#function#</cfoutput>

<!--- works everywhere --->
<cfset fieldName = "function">
<cfset variables[fieldName] = "function">
<cfoutput>variables[fieldName]</cfoutput>
```

### function name

```
<!--- works everywhere --->
<cffunction name="function">
    <cfargument name="function">
    
    <cfreturn arguments.function>
</cffunction>

<!--- works with ACF 10, 11, 2016 --->
<!--- doesn't work in Lucee at all --->
<cfoutput>#function("function")#</cfoutput>

<!--- works everywhere --->
<cfinvoke method="function" returnVariable="x">
    <cfinvokeargument name="function" value="function">
</cfinvoke>
<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

## script syntax

### variable

```
// doesn't work in ACF at all
// works with Lucee 5+
function = "function";
writeOutput(function);

// works everywhere
fieldName = "function";
variables[fieldName] = "function";
writeOutput(variables[fieldName]);
```

### function name

```
// doesn't work in ACF at all
// works with Lucee 5+
function function(function) {

    return arguments.function;
}

// doesn't work in ACF at all
// doesn't work in Lucee at all
wrieOutput( function("function") );

// works in ACF
// doesn't work in Lucee due to a different bug
writeOutput( invoke("", "function", { "function": "function" }) );
```

---

**In conclusion: Avoid using a reserved keyword!** It's inconsistent and leads to preventable bugs.

Comment: `invoke` bug has been reported here: [LDEV-3714](https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-3714)